# What is renderRow ()

Tags: react-native

I went through React-Native docs to figure out what is `renderRow()` but for some reason I am unable to comprehend what does it say from Facebook React-Native docs

This what the official docs says

### renderRow

*(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable*

Takes a data entry from the data source and its ids and should return a renderable component to be rendered as the row. By default the data is exactly what was put into the data source, but it's also possible to provide custom extractors. ListView can be notified when a row is being highlighted by calling highlightRow(sectionID, rowID). This sets a boolean value of adjacentRowHighlighted in renderSeparator, allowing you to control the separators above and below the highlighted row. The highlighted state of a row can be reset by calling highlightRow(null).

**[Question:]** Can someone please explain me this with example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is deprecated, use `FlatList` instead with the equivalent `renderItem` method. This is responsible of the actual rendering of each row based on the data records:

```
const data = [
  { key: '1', label: 'foo' },
  { key: '2', label: 'bar' }
]

renderTheItem = ({item}) => {
  return <Text>{item.label}</Text>
}

<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={this.renderTheItem}
/>
```

And the rendered result will be something like this:

```
<View>   --> coming from FlatList wrapper
 <Text key="1">foo</Text>   --> coming from the custom renderTheItem function
 <Text key="2">bar</Text>
</View>
```

It is mandatory to either add a unique key prop for each data record, or define a `keyExtractor` function. Also important to destruct the `item` in the renderer function with `({item})` as it has other meta parameters  as written in [documentation of FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem).

`renderItem({ item, index, separators}) => {}`